# qqnorm with color

Tags: r

I have a data in one column. lets call that column x.

This data is converted into log2 ratio. That means it has both positive and negative values.

I am plotting this data in R using qq norm.

What I have done so far:

```
d1<-read.table("testdata")
colorvector <- rep("black", length(d1$V1[is.finite(d1$V1)]))
colorvector[d1$V1[is.finite(d1$V1)] < -4] <- "red"
colorvector[d1$V1[is.finite(d1$V1)] > 4] <- "green"
### this means that the values above 4 will appear in green while the ones below -4 will appear in red#########

qqnorm(d1$V1[is.finite(d1$V1)], col=colorvector)
```

Some how this doesn't work.

But, if I give only:

```
qqnorm(d1$V1[is.finite(d1$V1)])
```

it does work.

example input

```
-2.49
-1.72
2.41
-1.72
-1.33
-0.95
-1.61
-2.27
-1.15
3.43
1.25
1.16
2.27
1.43
-1.66
-2.37
1.38
2.21
-2.17
2.65
-2.39
1.55
1.67
-1.68
-1.11
1.09
1.39
-2.97
1.33
2.6
-2.65
-3.97
-2.63
-2.51
1.3
-1.9
-2.01
-2.39
-5.03
-3.69
3.43
-2.81
-4.32
-1.82
-2.81
-inf
-3.13
-3.08
-2.86
inf
-1.86
1.43
-2.13
3.54
-2.39
1.96
-1.21
1.09
-2.17
-2.08
-2.17
-2.08
-2.39
-2.1
-3.04
-2.17
-2.13
3.19
-2.54
-2.51
-2.71
-2.97
-2.01
-2.32
-2.32
-2.1
-2.08
1.49
-1.76
-2.27
-1.59
-2.13
2.73
-2.15
-1.76
-1.82
-1.52
-3.44
-2.2
0.9
-2.65
-1.98
-1.94
-2.08
-2.23
0.97
2.54
-1.77
-2.4
-2.06
-1.83
-2.44
-2.17
-2.22
-2.65
-2.17
-2.13
-2.44
1.22
0.74
1.4
1.1
1.54
-2.44
-2.65
0.96
1.05
1.47
0.92
2.59
1.67
-2.39
0.82
1.38
-1.61
-2.22
-1.17
-2.82
3.19
-2.71
1.05
0.96
-1.39
1.19
1.42
-2.55
-2.15
4.31
-1.86
2.14
-2.19
-1.77
-2.97
2.48
-2.37
-2.1
-2.64
-2.39
1.17
1.11
-1.17
1.28
1.89
1.07
1.23
-2.44
1.33
1.34
-2.08
-1.99
1.17
-1.48
-3.39
-1.73
-2.08
-2.22
1.96
-2.86
1.31
1.87
1.15
3.19
2.35
1.58
1.01
0.87
-0.89
0.85
-1.27
0.89
1.39
1.37
-2.39
-2.27
-1.82
-2.86
-2.81
-1.96
-2.39
-1.71
-2.59
-2.44
2.79
1.73
2.36
0.97
1.3
-2.08
1.97
1.98
1.45
0.96
-1.48
-1.82
2.05
-2.76
-2.17
0.88
-1.35
-2.97
-2.17
2.41
-2.39
-2.44
-1.49
-1.96
-2.44
-3.49
-2.27
-2.15
-1.81
-2.08
-2.06
-2.06
-2.27
-2.82
-2.08
-2.71
-1.79
-2.13
1.16
-3.08
-2.39
-2.27
-2.22
-2.39
-2.08
1.48
0.82
2.63
-1.64
1.24
-2.23
2.08
-2.99
-2.65
1.8
1.87
2.13
-2.65
-1.36
-2.75
1.04
-2.49
3.19
-2.97
1.28
2.79
-2.49
-1.12
-1.25
-1.53
-1.27
-1.39
-1.86
-1.75
-2.71
-1.77
-1.82
-2.55
-4.97
-2.59
1.84
1.15
-1.59
1.3
1.44
1.19
1.57
1.38
1.35
-2.44
-4.03
-2.86
-1.55
-2.19
-2.39
2.48
-1.86
0.91
1.14
-1.89
0.69
-2.2
0.83
1.12
1.69
-2.82
-2.65
0.88
0.85
1.12
1.27
1.23
-2.32
-2.55
-2.23
-1.94
-3.97
-2.27
1.94
-2.06
-2.17
3.19
-2.27
-1.46
1.46
1.05
-2.17
-2.17
-1.88
2.95
-3.18
-1.57
-2.01
-1.79
-1.86
-2.15
-3.55
1.25
1.23
-1.79
-1.64
0.97
1.29
-2
0.96
1.04
-1.77
1.21
0.82
0.87
-3.08
-2.1
1.6
2.01
-1.54
-1.38
-2.13
-2.06
1.68
-2.97
-4.08
-2.44
-2.27
-2.39
-2.08
-2.37
-3.18
-2.42
-2.65
-2.13
1.16
1.11
-1.86
-2.1
-2.01
-2.48
-1.76
0.85
-2.5
-0.76
1.3
1.22
0.68
-1.94
-2.51
-2.39
2.95
-1.67
1.01
1.05
1.7
1
1.26
1.07
-1.38
1.27
-2.73
1.29
1.4
1.02
-2.49
-1.99
-2.44
-2.86
-1.51
-2.12
-2.65
1.42
2.09
-2.65
1.84
-2.23
-1.77
-1.86
-1.58
-1.77
3.25
-2.49
1
-1.54
1.41
0.64
1.67
1.05
1.76
1.01
1.26
-2.37
-2.13
1.56
1.14
-1.93
-2.13
-2.71
-3.03
-2.08
-2.65
-1.83
-2.81
-1.64
1.27
1.02
1.8
-2.17
1.78
0.7
-1.78
-1.75
1
1.44
0.96
0.96
0.99
1.05
1.12
-3.18
1.01
-2.15
1.31
1.65
1.04
1.02
1.05
-1.25
0.98
-1.62
2.26
-2.55
2.59
-1.99
-2.27
1.21
-1.6
1.21
-1.08
-0.72
1.15
1.16
-1.95
1.42
-2.17
1.94
2.19
-2.06
1.39
1.1
1.38
1.18
-1.81
-2.22
0.88
0.92
1.94
-1.39
1.3
-2.17
-1.94
-1.95
1.51
-1.55
-2.13
-2.06
1.05
-2.39
-2.17
-1.95
-1.98
-1.55
-2.53
-2.04
-2.66
-1.95
2.31
-2.13
1
3.19
0.73
2.01
-2.23
-2.17
-2.42
-2.04
-3.16
1.88
-1.95
-2.73
-2.81
-1.67
1.79
2.01
0.78
1.05
0.98
0.91
-1.57
-2.56
3.25
1.02
-1.59
-1.96
0.8
2.59
-2.2
2.79
-4.23
-1.9
-1.65
-2.73
-2.44
-1.95
1.46
1.7
1.88
-2.44
-2.65
1.19
1.04
-1.42
-0.71
1.16
3
-1.7
-2.08
-1.77
-2.23
1.19
-1.94
1.83
-3.97
-3.97
1.01
-5.32
```

Kindly, share your experience/knowledge in letting me overcome this hurdle.

Thank you

Comment: Please, provide example input.

Comment: The question has been edited and the example input has been put in.

Comment: I tried to duplicate your error, but the code worked. Could there be some issue with the underlying data file? For a test you could also first make a new vector with only the finite numbers, and then use that vector for graphing and assigning colors - that might help narrow down the issue

Comment: Oh Yeah, it works fine after removing inf from the input data but is their a way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `inf`in your example data. You need `Inf` with a capital `I` instead.